# Using RocksDB as a local cache for image thumbnails

Tags: caching, key-value-store, rocksdb, database, nosql

I'm building a desktop application for macOS that allows a user to browse a collection of videos. Generating thumbnails for each video is a relatively expensive operation so I'd like to cache any thumbnails that have been generated. This cache does not need to persist across application launches. Speed is not that critical because just about anything is faster than decoding frames of a video.

I'm considering using RocksDB to store the thumbnails and was wondering if this is an appropriate use of RocksDB. Most of the RocksDB documentation involves setting and getting strings as values, but in recent versions the addition of `PinnableSlice` appears to make it easier for storing binary data. In my application, I'd be storing heavily compressed JPEG data for thumbnails up to 512 x 512px.

Is there anything I should take into consideration when using RocksDB in this fashion? Are there any configuration options that would be beneficial to tune or adjust for such a use-case? I would prefer if RocksDB kept a low in-memory overhead because I'm willing to take the performance hit of reading back from disk when a thumbnail is needed.

(And if using RocksDB as an image cache is a really bad idea to begin with, then I'd like to better understand why.)

Comment: Why not storing the file name/path as key and the path to the thumbnail image as value? The actual image can be stored in some directory on disk.

Comment: Yep, a totally valid approach. The only concern I'd have is that I could be generating thousands of thumbnails. In most implementations that involve storing thumbnails as individual files, you inevitably have to start "sharding" across multiple sub-directories.  I love the simplicity of an (almost) single file DB, much like SQLite, and mostly curious how RocksDB might perform in such a situation. I'm trying to better understand of it's completely the wrong tool for the job, a reasonable if not perfect tool, or a great choice for something like this.